# Is there a method to load a 2D array into three 1D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a more efficient way or even a method to load a 2D `numpy` array `data[n,m]` into three 1D arrays `X[n*m]`, `Y[n*m]`, and `Z[n*m]` than looping over the indices? What I did is:

```py
n = len(data[:,0])
m = len(data[0,:])
X = zeros(n*m)
Y = zeros(n*m)
Z = zeros(n*m)
c = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        X[c] = i
        Y[c] = j
        Z[c] = data[i,j]
        c += 1
```

Comment: Can you provide an example array?

Comment: Also your X and Y arrays (lists?) are not 1D, they still have "size" `n*m`

Comment: What do you mean by "load a 2D array"?  What do you mean "array"--`X`, `Y`, and `Z` seem to be lists, but `data` seems to be something else--perhaps a numpy array? `X` and `Y` seem to be rather boring wastes of space with indices in them. 

You need to be a lot more concrete. It would help if you explained what you actually hope to accomplish and showed some actual data.

Comment: There's a chance you might just want to use `data.flat` or, umm.....nothing at all.

Comment: That edit don't make much sense either. x,y is simply set to the range of n and m. And z hold all the values. I think you should rather show some example input and output to make your question easier to understand. Are you trying to replicate `np.indicies`for X and Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your codes actually does what you intended. This should be the equivalent.

```
X,Y =  np.indices(data.shape)
Z = data.ravel()
X = X.ravel()
Y = Y.ravel()
```

Comment: ravel() instead of flatten(), unless you want to make copies